# Visual Studio - MDF File - Data provider could not be loaded

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express, sql-server-2008-express

I have an MDF File in a Visual Studio project.
On my laptop, I can double click on this, and it opens up in a Visual studio window, in Server Explorer.

If I try this on my pc in the office, i get "Data provider identified by Guid '' could not be loaded

I've just re-installed VS2010, to no avail.

SQL Express 2008 is installed and working.

Any ideas?

Comment: I ended up having to rebuild windows (unrelated issue) so guess I'll never know...

Answer (score 2):

I've come accross a solution that worked for me. I had this problem with an `.sdf file` (SQL Server Compact Edition).

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio;
2. Edit `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ServerExplorer\DefaultView.SEView` (could be under '%AppData%\Roaming')and remove the connection with the wrong Provider. If you do not know which of the provider is failing, simply delete the file
3. Open Visual Studio and try to open your .mdf or .sdf file

This solution come from this site: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552006/unable-to-create-data-connection-in-server-explorer

Comment: You legend - this works for an MDF as well. My problem arose whilst messing with MySQL drivers installing and uninstalling - how that affects SQL Server Express drivers is be-he-yond me...